# Unexpected behavior in javascript datetime

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, while-loop

try below code

```js
let startDate = new Date();
const lastDate = new Date();
lastDate.setMonth(11,31);

const timeArray = [];

while(startDate <lastDate){
  timeArray.push(startDate);
  console.log(startDate)
  startDate =new Date(startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth()+1)) 
}
console.log('==================================');
console.log(timeArray)
```

But result shows as below

```
Thu Nov 03 2022 09:12:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Sat Dec 03 2022 09:12:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
==================================
[
Sat Dec 03 2022 09:12:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Tue Jan 03 2023 09:12:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
]
```

When I console the 'startDate' just after the array push it shows as expected , But when I console log the time array it has been shifted . Can someone explain this?

Comment: Well, you did call setMonth on the Date object.  Perhaps you find it unexpected that it set the month of the Date object that you pushed into the array?

Comment: try logging after 
> `startDate =new Date(startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth()+1))`
You will get the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe below is the code you were intending to write, where you clone the `startDate` and then modify **the clone** instead of modifying the original.

```js
let startDate = new Date();
const lastDate = new Date();
lastDate.setMonth(11,31);

const timeArray = [];

while(startDate <lastDate){
  timeArray.push(startDate);
  console.log(startDate)
  startDate = new Date(startDate); // uncouple it from the other date
  startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth()+1)
}
console.log('==================================');
console.log(timeArray)
```